# How to dump a DirectDraw Surface from memory to file?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, directx, sprite

I'm reverse engineering an ancient game that uses the DirectDraw API within DirectX 7. The aim is to export the sprites (in this case, a direct draw surface) from memory to a file. I can see that they're using a `IDirectDrawSurface7` (the variable is called `lpDDSrcSurface`).

Is there anyway to export the contents of a `IDirectDrawSurface7` to a file? I suppose the easiest way would be to export it to a DDS file? I know in DX9, `D3DXCreateTextureFromFile` can import a DDS file into memory and `D3DXSaveTextureToFile` can export a texture to a DDS file.

Note: the DirectX9 version of a `IDirectDrawSurface7` is `IDirect3DSurface9`.

Comment: I found `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile` for DirectX 9. Now I just need something like this for 7. :\